# How to count identical bytes

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two long arrays of bytes and I need to compute how many bytes on corresponding positions are identical. My solution (in JAVA) is as follows:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < t.length;i++)
      if (t[i] == spb[i])
        sum++;
```

Since this part of my program takes substantial time, I wonder if I can make this any faster

Obviously the length of the two arrays is identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using previously-suggested "concurrent threads to compute partial sums for sections of the array" method (which I will comment on in a later paragraph), you can use two simple techniques to speed up the loop:  (1) `?:` tertiary operator instead of `if` test, and (2)  loop unrolling.

On my old 2GHz system, using gcj java compiler, each of those techniques gives a few percent of speedup.  The improvement you get on your machine (if any) may be compiler or jvm dependent.

Code examples:

```
    if (t[i] == spb[i]) sum++;
```

goes to

```
    sum += t[i] == spb[i] ? 1 : 0;
```

and

```
    public static int counts (byte[] A, byte[] B) {
       int i, count, L=A.length;
       for (count=i=0; i<L; i++)
          count += A[i]==B[i] ? 1 : 0;
       return count;
    }
```

goes to (for example)

```
   public static int counts (byte[] A, byte[] B) {
        final int S=8;
        int i, count, L=A.length-S;
        for(count=i=0; i<L; i+=S) {
            count += A[i+0]==B[i+0] ? 1 : 0;
            count += A[i+1]==B[i+1] ? 1 : 0;
            count += A[i+2]==B[i+2] ? 1 : 0;
            count += A[i+3]==B[i+3] ? 1 : 0;
            count += A[i+4]==B[i+4] ? 1 : 0;
            count += A[i+5]==B[i+5] ? 1 : 0;
            count += A[i+6]==B[i+6] ? 1 : 0;
            count += A[i+7]==B[i+7] ? 1 : 0;
        }
        for (; i<L+S; ++i)
            count += A[i]==B[i] ? 1 : 0;
        return count;
    }
```

Loop unrolling could be done with `S` having a value larger or smaller than the `S=8` shown above.  However, in the tests I ran, `S=16` showed little improvement over `S=8`.  Some sample timings, with 202MB arrays:

```
A. 51094384 matches in 3.421857144 sec. (original loop)
E. 51094384 matches in 3.212364808 sec. (use ?: value)
F. 51094384 matches in 2.953596272 sec. (?: + S=8 unroll)
G. 51094384 matches in 2.949984214 sec. (?: + S=16 unroll)
```

In this run, E. timing is 6% less than A., while F. and G. are 8% less than E., and 14% less than A.  (Other timings, not shown, verified that a previous answer's claim that "requesting the field of an object (t.length) takes more time than a local variable", is irrelevant.)

Regarding use of concurrent threads:  Suppose you use three threads.  Among other methods, you could let thread `i` treat contiguous bytes in the `i`'th third of each array, or you could let thread `i` handle every third byte, that is, bytes with index mod 3 = `i`.  It would be worthwhile to benchmark the difference in execution time.  I would expect it to be different, on different machines, depending on cache sizes and regimes.

Answer (score 6):

If the arrays are very long, you could use multiple concurrent threads to compute partial sums for sections of the array, and then sum up the partial sums.

Comment: Since this is a CPU-bound activity, this would only make sense to do as long as `number of threads` == `number of cores`, right?

Comment: @matt b, it's not CPU-bound, it's memory bandwidth bound. The answer to your question depends on the machine. It may be `number of sockets` instead, or oversubscribing might even help depending on the architecture of the machine.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, you're basically doing the right thing (at least for a single thread - Simon's idea of using multiple threads is a good one). How much time is this taking, and how long are the arrays? It ought to be pretty quick.

You *might* be able to speed it up by creating a `ByteBuffer` around the byte array, then using `asLongBuffer` to create a `LongBuffer` wrapping it again. You could then check 8 bytes at a time (as longs), only checking a single byte at a time when the `long` comparison returns false. This would be significantly more complicated code though - and I wouldn't be *at all* surprised to find that it's actually a lot slower.

Comment: The latter approach is pretty much what strcmp does in optimized implementations, so presumably it's likely to be faster if large parts of the array are identical.

Comment: @NickJohnson: Well, strcmp gets to do that in a very highly optimized way - it depends on how much redirection Java is adding via LongBuffer and ByteBuffer.

Comment: That's true. Somehow I missed that this was Java. :)

Comment: @Nick:  `strcmp()` is doing something different.  In `strcmp()`, finding one discrepancy means you stop the comparison and return a value.  This program has to count the number of discrepancies.

Comment: @DavidThornley I know - I was simply pointing out that it successfully uses a word-by-word comparison to skip over large regions of matches, like Jon suggested for this function. In C, this would almost certainly be faster unless the string had a lot of mismatches; in Java, probably not so much, as Jon points out.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = t.length - 1;i >= 0 ;i--)
if (t[i] == spb[i])
    sum++;
```

In principle, requesting the field of an object (t.length) takes more time than a local variable (i). If you iterate from last to first, the most expensive instruction is executed only once.

Comment: While (at least on my machine) this does run faster by than the OP code by 15%, if the reason was avoiding the length operator on each iteration then `for(int i = 0, length = t.length; i < length; i++)` would also be 15% faster, but replacing the request for the length with a local variable is not significantly faster ( array length of one, ten or hundred million ). IIRC, there is a specific optimisation in the JVM to hoist the length of arrays used in for loops.